# Java regex issue

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Requirement : String "richText" which can include plain text +anchor tag. The anchor tag is rewritten to modify its target, append JS, etc

*Issue*: 
The pattern matcher find() & appendReplacement()  works fine till there is no special character ***"$"*** in the anchor tag. It throws an *exception* when $ is part of anchor tag.

*Line 1* fixes up the exception part but creates an issue if **"$" or "\"** is present in plain text since plain text now has additional escape characters around the above 2 special characters(bcoz of quoteReplacement()). How do I strip the additional escape characters from plain text(undo affect of quoteReplacement)?

Method:

```
    String richText = Matcher.quoteReplacement(rText); //Line 1-escape characters   
    String anchorTagPattern = "<a[^>]*?href\\s*=[^>]*>(.*?)</a>";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(richText.length());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(anchorTagPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(richText);
    while (matcher.find()) {
               String aTag = matcher.group();
               .......
               String formattedAnchorTag = rewriteTag(aTag);
               matcher.appendReplacement(result, formattedAnchorTag); ....
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);
    //Plain text with $ \ has some additional escape characters because of Line 1. How    to remove them:
```

rText entered is

```
Plain text having $. Anchor tag to be rewritten is <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google$</a>
```

If Line1 in the method- quoteReplacement is commented then I get *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference*
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:724)

If I leave it, the exception goes away but the string returned is

```
Plain text having \$. Anchor tag to be rewritten is <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google$</a>
```

Comment: after `richText` is assigned, but before `anchorTagPattern` is created, what does `richText` look like for error inputs?  also, what does `rText` look like for error inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matcher.quoteReplacement` should not be called on `rText`. The first question mark in the pattern seems superfluous. Only `rewriteTag` may be the cause.

---

```
formattedAnchorTag = Matcher.quoteReplacement(formattedAnchorTag);
matcher.appendReplacement(result, formattedAnchorTag);
```

Comment: That should not matter. The source text may contain $ without special significance.